# Multiple CountDownTimer in Recyclerview not in Sync

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I've multiple countdown in a RecyclerView. Which is in sync(seconds changes at same time) initially but after scrolling up and down for sometime, the CountDown loses it's sync. Seconds changes are not in Sync and also the difference(milliseconds) between 1st and 2nd views changes. Initially the difference between 1st and 2nd dates were 10 seconds, after scrolling couple of times it went up to 20 seconds.

**Adapter class**

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private NavController navController;
    private ArrayList<Date> datesArray;

    public EventAdapter(NavController navController, ArrayList<Date> datesArray) {
        this.navController = navController;
        this.datesArray = datesArray;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        IntroAdapter.ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (layoutInflater == null) {
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        }
        context = parent.getContext();
        EventLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.event_layout, parent, false);
        return new EventAdapter.ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.timer == null) {
            holder.timer = new CountDownTimer(Utils.getDifferenceInMilli(datesArray.get(position)), 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                    holder.itemView.tvTime.setText(Utils.getCountDownTime(l, 0));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    holder.timer.cancel();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datesArray.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CountDownTimer timer;
        EventLayoutBinding itemView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull EventLayoutBinding itemView) {
            super(itemView.getRoot());
            this.itemView = itemView;
        }

    }
}
```

`getDifferenceInMilli()` returns the millisecond difference between current date and provided date.

Is there any way to maintain the sync after scrolling ?

Comment: if timer is not null you should cancel it and recreate it

Comment: Thanks man. It's working. I was trying to create a Global CountDown service. Do you think that a cleaner approach ?

Comment: Countdown for each ViewHolder is fine. No need for global